# Facebook channel shows as "Error"

Tags: botframework

Under my channels, the Facebook one's status is "Error". But I can't see what it is in that state. I have removed the channel and re-added it but it is still the same.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the "Error" text in the status list it will provide a more detailed messages.